# DATEADD, DATEPART not returning desired results

Tags: sql-server-2008, dateadd, datepart

I am not sure if my brain is working because it is Monday. I want to add a single year to the current year but I am getting undesired results.

Here is what I am getting:

```
select current_timestamp 
Output:2012-04-23 09:57:45.777

select DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEPART(YEAR,current_timestamp)) 
Output: 1906-07-06 00:00:00.000

select DATEPART(year,current_timestamp) 
Output: 2012
```

Something as simple as this and for some reason I am failing to catch the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DATEADD(YEAR, 1, current_timestamp)
```

if you only want the date part:

```
select DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, current_timestamp) ))
```

Comment: Ha! I knew it was something stupid. I want to have my DATEPART on the outside instead of the inside. ie. select DATEPART(YYYY, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, current_timestamp))

Comment: In my example above i was trying to only return the year: select DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEPART(YEAR,current_timestamp)) but instead I needed to perform the datepart like so: select DATEPART(YYYY, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, current_timestamp))

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

select DATEPART(YYYY,(DATEADD(YEAR, 1,current_timestamp)))

--It will give result 2016

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATEADD(YEAR, 1, current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT cast(DATEPART(YEAR,current_timestamp) as datetime);
```

go
return 
1905-07-10 00:00:00.000
that's the problem

```
select dateadd(year,1, current_timestamp);
```

go
return 
2017-07-25 23:13:49.700